# Amazon S3 EPIPE Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

**UPDATE:** got it working from the [commandline](http://www.timkay.com/aws/) after add a full access policy permissions to that user. Now when I do it with Node there is no error but I can't see the files in my s3 file manager.

I keep getting an EPIPE error using Amazon's S3 service.

I am a little stuck and unsure of how to proceed.

I am using Node.js with the [Knox module](https://github.com/learnboost/knox).

Here is my code:

```
var client = knox.createClient({
    key: amazonAccessKeyId,
    secret: amazonSecretAccessKey,
    bucket: amazonBucketName
});

function moveFiles() {
    moveUploadedFile(req.files['aps-file'].path,'/aps-products.csv', this.parallel());
    moveUploadedFile(req.files['perry-craft-roof-file'].path,'/perry-craft-roof-products.csv', this.parallel());
    res.end('successful!');
}

function moveUploadedFile(srcPath, dstPath, callback) {
    client.putFile(srcPath, dstPath, { 'x-amz-acl': 'public' }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(new Error("Error uploading file for " + dstPath + ": " + err.message), srcPath);
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log('Finished writing file ' + dstPath + ' to Amazon S3 Cloud');
        callback(null, srcPath);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so these are the steps I took to resolve this problem:

1. Installed aws commandline tool you can find it here: http://www.timkay.com/aws/
2. Added a Full Access (Administrator Access) policy to the s3 user I created.
3. Made sure I can write to that bucket using the command: `aws put /file/to/put /new-file`.
4. Removed `{'x-amz-acl': 'public' }` it should be `'public-read'` otherwise it will not add the files to s3 (without errors). Note that `{'x-amz-acl': 'private' }` works too.